# com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid column name 'VALUE'

Tags: exception, split, sql-server-2017

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid column name 'VALUE'

with following code

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION [tablename].FIND_IN_SET (@Search_For nvarchar(max), @Search_This nvarchar(max))
RETURNS int AS
BEGIN
RETURN CASE WHEN (SELECT count(1) FROM STRING_SPLIT(@Search_This,',') WHERE VALUE=@Search_For) = 0 THEN '0' ELSE '1' END
END
```

Issue is on sql server 2017 with version 14.0.3356.20 and its works fine on 14.0.1000.169

Anything missing here?

Comment: Are you using a case sensitive collation on the other environment? `STRING_SPLIT` returns a column `value`, not `VALUE`.

Comment: Side note, `[tablename]` is a *really* odd choice of a name for a schema...

Comment: Thanks for the updates. I have shared the tablename for just illustration purpose. I need to check collation as you pointed out